# Cold observable's Scheduler.CurrentThread - in which thread will it run?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm new to RX and starting to understand a few concepts.. that one I didn't find on the web.

I'm using a timer in my code:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), schedulerProvider.CurrentThread);
// where schedulerProvider.CurrentThread is actually Scheduler.CurrentThread
```

I understand that Timer is a **Cold Observable**, and every subscriber will get its private timer that will run for 2 seconds from when it subscribed.

I'm creating that cold observable in **`thread1`** and subscribing to it with **`thread2`** [,**`thread3`**, **`thread4`** etc...]

So the question is: **in which thread will it run?**

Please provide a source.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Thanks for the detailed answer. Now I know that my question has an issue.The scheduler that passed as second parameter is **NOT** for subscribers scheduling, but for running the Timer.
Most of RX operators runs on the same thread by default, but Timer is one (of several) exceptional. By default, the timer itself will run on the Thread Pool, and call OnNext on its same thread. If you ask it to use CurrentThread scheduler, the timer itself will run on the same thread (like most of Rx operators) and subscribers will be called on the same thread. (this is not very recommended though for regular use cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do run some tests to find out?

Here's what I did:

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0), Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
```

The produced:

```
12
12
```

Then I tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
```

That produced:

```
12
13
```

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
```

That produced:

```
11
27
```

All of this boils down to `Scheduler.CurrentThread` capturing the current thread context **at the time that the `Scheduler.CurrentThread` parameter is evaluated**.

In the first block of code it was captured **at the time that the timer was created** - in other words, my console thread.

In the final block it was captured **after the timer fired** so it captured the thread that the timer fired on.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I was busy, I like your answer, I feel something is missing here, You very helped me but I’m waiting until I verify your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Now I fully understand how this works. But I disagree with part of your explanation: *In the first block of code it was captured at the time that the timer was created - in other words, my console thread.* I think this is wrong because of the Observable.Timer() docs: *Returns an observable sequence that produces a single value after the specified relative due time has elapsed, using the specified scheduler to **run the timer**.* So the first example ran the Timer in the Console thread, and then just called OnNext() on the same thread naturally

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect that minor fix =]

Comment: @Yitzchak - Thanks for the feedback, but I do read my answer "at the time that the timer was created" as being the same as "using the specified scheduler to run the timer". Can you explain why you see a difference?

Comment: actually you’re right, it’s just my question that was wrong, I’ve edited it. Thanks (for many answers you gave me in many situations)