# How to synchronize results from an observable in System.Reactive

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, system.reactive, blockingcollection

So Rx is single-threaded by default. In the case of the `Sample` operator it's not. In my ASPNetCore application, I want to be able to have `Subscribe` run on the main thread (single thread). I tried using `ObserveOn` passing in `SynchronizationContext.Current`, but it's `null` in ASPNetCore.

A possible solution will be to push all items into `BlockingCollection` then read from it, but that kinda adds another layer of complexity.

```cs
      Console.WriteLine ($"Main Thread:  {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
      var source = Observable
        .Interval (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (1))
        .Sample (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (2));

      source
        .Subscribe (
          data => {
            Console.WriteLine ($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // different thread
            // Here each onNext is invoked asynchronously 
            // But I have a shared resource that I would like to invoke synchronously. 
          }
        );
```

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule it on the main thread, you should specify a scheduler for your operators.

```
        var source = Observable
          .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Scheduler.CurrentThread);
```

Please note that this is blocking (since it's doing work on the main thread) - which is similar to your enumerable sample.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635642/cold-observables-scheduler-currentthread-in-which-thread-will-it-run) by @Enigmativity.

Comment: that's very true. Using `ToEnumerable()` or `Scheduler.CurrentThread` is blocking and actually not what I want. I'll update my question a bit

Comment: Yes, but your question still says "I want to be able to have Subscribe run on the main thread (single thread)". Not sure how that's possible since AFAIK asp.net doesn't have a dispatcher

Comment: My question is to ask for ways to handle such a situation. I'm currently working on using a `BlockingCollection` to synchronize all actions handled in `Subscribe`. I'll share my implementation soon